# PHP web Login not keeping user signed in.

Tags: php, mysql

I have This PhP code that i have been using on a few of my website. But for some reason i have developed a little problem.

Right now if you try and go to a page that is protected with this code you are redirected to the index.php page where it has a forum for you to sign in. Once the user is signed in it takes them to home.php This all works fine. But the problem is if the user goes to settings.php or prety much any other page other then the home page i would say 40% of the time it redirects them back to the index.php page to sign back in. I thought is was do to time but you can sign in and hen instantly go to add.php and it redirects you to index.php, if i go back a page (back to home.php) and click on another page (example remove.php) it allows me to go there. I dont understand why it works some times and not other?

The code is the same on all pages i use an to request the code below.
**connection.php**

```
<?php
    $con = new mysqli("localhost","****","********","********");
                if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
                  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
                }
    ?>
```

**restrict_access.php**

```
<?php
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
  session_start();
}
$MM_authorizedUsers = "9,10";
$MM_donotCheckaccess = "false";

// *** Restrict Access To Page: Grant or deny access to this page
function isAuthorized($strUsers, $strGroups, $UserName, $UserGroup) { 
  // For security, start by assuming the visitor is NOT authorized. 
  $isValid = False; 

  // When a visitor has logged into this site, the Session variable MM_Username set equal to their username. 
  // Therefore, we know that a user is NOT logged in if that Session variable is blank. 
  if (!empty($UserName)) { 
    // Besides being logged in, you may restrict access to only certain users based on an ID established when they login. 
    // Parse the strings into arrays. 
    $arrUsers = Explode(",", $strUsers); 
    $arrGroups = Explode(",", $strGroups); 
    if (in_array($UserName, $arrUsers)) { 
      $isValid = true; 
    } 
    // Or, you may restrict access to only certain users based on their username. 
    if (in_array($UserGroup, $arrGroups)) { 
      $isValid = true; 
    } 
    if (($strUsers == "") && false) { 
      $isValid = true; 
    } 
  } 
  return $isValid; 
}

$MM_restrictGoTo = "index.php?error=3";
if (!((isset($_SESSION['MM_Username'])) && (isAuthorized("",$MM_authorizedUsers, $_SESSION['MM_Username'], $_SESSION['MM_UserGroup'])))) {   
  $MM_qsChar = "?";
  $MM_referrer = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
  if (strpos($MM_restrictGoTo, "?")) $MM_qsChar = "&";
  if (isset($QUERY_STRING) && strlen($QUERY_STRING) > 0) 
  $MM_referrer .= "?" . $QUERY_STRING;
  $MM_restrictGoTo = $MM_restrictGoTo. $MM_qsChar . "accesscheck=" . urlencode($MM_referrer);
  header("Location: ". $MM_restrictGoTo); 
  exit;
}
?>
```

Comment: put `session_start()` at the top of the page;  don't check for it first.

Answer (score 1):

I would try removing the check on isset($_SESSION) I would assume that would return true and session_start is never being called.

$_SESSION is a registered global in PHP and something that PHP always creates.  You can modify this global even if session_start is not called and isset returns true for an empty array().

Please let me know if removing the isset check works for you.

Just simply change this

```
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
  session_start();
}
```

To simply this

```
session_start();
```

I am guessing that it is working sometimes and not others because you are setting the session variable manually and then checking for it which will work, however the sessions are not being written to the filesystem or database so there are times when the page requests another script and that's when it will fail because it's a new page request and the session is not being written between page requests.

Comment: Thank you, i am trying it out now... I will post the outcome.